# Object in extension does not get initialized in my web page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

My extension has a object called "Transcribe" that does not get initialized when my webpage make a call to it, I get the following error message every time the function is called, It tells me that somehow i have not made correct call to the extension ? I have include the manifest file that loads backgound and footpedal scripts onload. Please treat my question as novice in JS and Chrome extension.

```
VM1018:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: Transcribe is not defined
    at Object.attemptExtensionConnection (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21), <anonymous>:52:260)
    at Object.init (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21), <anonymous>:46:152)
    at testfootpedal (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21), <anonymous>:121:19)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM1065 author:1)
```

Background.js

```
    Transcribe.FootPedal.AppCommunication.init(), chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    showInstructionsWindow()
}), chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    showInstructionsWindow()
});
var showInstructionsWindow = function() {
    chrome.app.window.create("instructions/index.html", {
        bounds: {
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        },
        resizable: !1
    })
};
```

Manifest.json

```
    {
   "app": {
      "background": {
         "scripts": [ "transcribe/foot_pedal.js", "background.js" ]
      }
   },
   "description": "Extension for Dictalogic to support foot pedals",
   "externally_connectable": {
       "ids": [

      // Alternatively, to match all extensions and apps, specify only
      // "*".
      "*"
    ],
      "matches": [ "*://*.dictalogic.com/*", "*://localhost/*" ]
   },
      "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png",
      "24": "icon_24.png",
      "48": "icon_48.png"
   },
   "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAru3N8Mkyxa9dSKX3N3BeSGikRKOtN8WUnEG2UzVTRh0aI0pmFuePGBsF/jQwHfy9cOm1qg5VU9aXe/bMeN9kTbAY1oL1AkCCiq4MX+kUIbKwW3ggTLro0h+XE+8KHmgaHWZycIsTVlQ+9TRgTYIF0LAkQLzPg2CB2OylaA+WT28eaV5L3LZW84ocDtUhqVV2YNE2KgEML8hpE7PH51YsRGQq3NFXk4q6csprVemBLzzMYtorpcNUBRpf6SetW4HYPSjjsibSRxMIV0VmGEMi3aAmsa8LaMh5MtnHBPskVxaZ+PqZD6Osz5UKxkfquvjQdn6INWR1NAigMhVwixVAiQIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "minimum_chrome_version": "38.0",
   "name": "Dictalogic foot pedal extension",
   "optional_permissions": [ {
      "usbDevices": [ {
         "productId": 255,
         "vendorId": 1523
      }, {
         "productId": 536,
         "vendorId": 1972
      }, {
         "productId": 21845,
         "vendorId": 1204
      } ]
   } ],
   "permissions": [ "usb", "hid" , "*://localhost/*" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2.2.0"
}
```

MyPage.html

```
  FootPedal.init();
```

Comment: It's not an extension, it's a chrome app, which is an entirely different thing. Extensions can run content scripts in browser tabs and thus expose JavaScript objects by adding that code in a `<script>` element. Apps can't do that.

Comment: I followed this guide https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted - if what i have created is an app then how can i change it to extension ?

Comment: The starting point is correct but then you've deviated into apps. Extensions can't use chrome.usb API (as well as `usbDevices`) and don't have `app` key in the manifest. See also [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: My aim is to integrate a foot pedal with my browser recorder, If i can't use chrome.usb API in extension then is there any way i could create app and at the same time allow my webpage to initialize object in app ?

Comment: To expose a JavaScript object on the web page you'd have to write an additional extension that communicates with your app via [cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external). The extension will have a content script that inserts a `<script>` element with the interface object. Alternatively, your web page can use [messaging directly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) to your app as is, but without the said JavaScript object available.

Comment: Thank you for setting me right, I will do bit more research to get my facts right and create that bridge i am missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165579/discussion-between-ron12345-and-woxxom).